# Is it bad practice to do an Ajax request directly from a jQuery plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, export

So I'm writing a jQuery plugin that relies heavily on content exports using URIs.  Using just JavaScript, it works fine on all non-IE browsers.  There is a method of downloading things using ActiveX in IE, but it frequently blocks that, so I found that I can only download through PHP with IE.  So for all non-IE browsers I would use JS, but I would do Ajax with IE.  Would this be a bad/inefficient practice?

Comment: Ajax uses JS to make the request, so your question isn't clear.

Comment: Well of couse you would be making the request _with_ Ajax, but what I'm saying is, is it bad to reference a PHP file from a jQuery plugin?

Comment: What do you mean 'reference a PHP file'?

Comment: Well, doesn't an Ajax call "reference a PHP file"?

Answer (score 0):

I am GUESSING that you are trying to download files? It is possible that these downloads work on other browsers because the other browsers are GUESSING as to the type of file (i.e. image, document etc.).

If no MIME-TYPE (such as "image/png") or CONTENT-TYPE ("application/javascript") is set in the HTTP response headers, then this will NOT work in IE because IE (in this specific case) actually tries to follow standards and doesn't assume anything to do with the file.