# Exporting HTML data to Excel on Mac using URI

Tags: javascript, excel, data-uri

So I'm using data URIs to export HTML data to Excel, the problem is, it doesn't work on IE (which I'm fixing), and it doesn't work on Mac.  It exports it to the raw HTML, which is obviously not what I want.  Here is my HTML (which is exported to Excel perfectly on Windows:

```
<html>

    <body>

        <table>

             <tr><td>Hello</td></tr><tr><td>Hi</td><td>Hola</td></tr>

        </table>

    </body>

</html>
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```
excelData = $(".excelData").html();

window.location.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + excelData;
```

Does it have something to do with a different MIME type on Mac? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, the things that young people try to do with data URIs... :)  I think that it doesn't work on IE is by design, data URIs work for a very limited range of uses there. Which browser are you using on Mac OS?

Comment: Chrome.  Sorry if I'm totally inexperienced with URIs, but how would you do it?

Comment: The safest and most compatible way would be to have the data sent by the server as a proper URL, with the correct content-type header set.

Comment: You mean by PHP? I'm planning on using that for IE, but could you post some code?

Comment: In PHP, send a `header("Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel");` and then the data. If you're going to do it anyway, why not use it for all browsers?

Comment: Well, I'd like to turn this exporting in to a jQuery plugin, so if it just used Ajax what would be the point? But would that header work on Mac?

Comment: Well, depends on what you mean by "work". If Excel is not installed on the Mac, you will never get to see the actual file's contents; you will just be presented with a download option as there is no way for the browser to render the file. I don't know what currently happens when you use the data: URI

Comment: Well, of course we would have to assume that they have excel, but if they do, would the data be exported on all browsers/OS's?

Comment: sending a file (not through an Ajax request, but by setting `location` to it or opening a new window) is definitely the safest way that is guaranteed to work with the biggest set of browsers out there. Whether and how it'll work on Mac even with MS Office installed, I can't say, I don't have Office

Comment: But then it wouldn't be a jQuery plugin.  Is there any way to do it through JavaScript?

Comment: not safely, no, as far as I know. (There may be some HTML5 magic around, but that again has the downside that it won't work in older browsers.) It might be worth asking another question specifically about that, though

Comment: I already did, but someone was rude and then didn't answer the question.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891447/is-it-bad-practice-to-do-an-ajax-request-directly-from-a-jquery-plugin) question.

Comment: Mmm, that question isn't completely touching the point though IMO. It should be more like, "can I generate an Excel file using pure JavaScript (no server-side logic) that is opened in the browser's Excel plugin?" then to go on explaining how you used `data:` URIs and how those don't work in certain circumstances (IE, etc.)

Comment: Okay, so I should just scrap the plugin then?

Comment: As said, you could ask another question that goes more in that direction. It *could* be that it's impossible to do entirely in JavaScript, though, but it might be worth asking around first

Comment: You're welcome. If something comes out of it, let me know, I'd be interested to know.